# flutter doctor - This app can't run on your pc

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, virus

I have this error in my windows 8.1 system 64-bit, anytime I try to run `flutter doctor` it shows
[image]

And this happened after a friend of mine inserted his USB Flash drive in my system some apps did not run but I was able to fix it by re-installing the apps but for my flutter I don't know exactly how to fix it cause I have tried changing the flutter SDK folder with a different one but it didn't work please what can I do to make it work

Comment: Dou you have Powershell 5.0 and git installed?

Comment: @ yes I have pw 7 and git